# What makes the identities interesting?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

I am a beginning master student.I sometimes see  some identities ,relations or equations somewhere and people say about it " Oh,what a nice elegant identity."

But unfortunately  i can't say it like some good mathematicians lol:)
For example someone finds a good formula. But first of all i think how do this person thinks this formula and get this result? Where will this result be used later etc. When i look at an identity at first sight  i want to see that the identity is perfect:) thats all.

I wanted to ask this question because I want to learn the depth , philosophy and secret of this work i want to derive some  elegant  ,full of mind of identities,new kind of  special numbers etc like bright  mathematicians.  i also believe my question will guide some curious people.

For example i want to give a concrete example for you.

Here is a Ramanujan's  identity.
$$
\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4 k) !(1103+26390 k)}{(k !)^{4} 396^{4 k}}=\frac{1}{\pi}
$$

i want to learn  why this formula is perfect.I think left side gives infinite sum  the right hand side is  finite result and expressed in ${\pi}$ term. But How did Ramanujan think this formula? How did he arise this idea? another example "what makes a binomial identity interesting?" or the story of bernoulli numbers?etc.

You can give some examples of good identities and explain them or give some references:) Thanks for your answers and advices.

Comment: Trying to get into the mind of Ramanujan on this sort of identity is fruitless. You’d have to have a very rare mind t9 think like him - as far as we know only one such mind has existed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call that Ramanujan series "elegant". It's certainly "remarkable" in terms of how quickly it converges. Euler's identity $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$ is frequently called one of the most elegant results in all of mathematics...

Comment: When you have 1000 ideas pretty deeply understood, then, sometimes, idea 1001 arises on its own. And in this case just a bunch of ideas are useful. One or two can also be elegant.

Comment: Much of what we value in identities comes with experience. Obviously, we can always explain identities with proofs, but how the first person got there can still seem a mystery. That can be true for all mathematical result, not just identities.

Comment: Elegance is also generally a rather gray notion, a matter of taste. Some results are deep but not necessarily elegant (think Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which relates a geometric property - area, to a purely algebraic one, - anti-derivatives; this is deep, but not necessarily elegant. Ditto the Four Color Theorem in Graph Theory).

Some things are elegant because they express a relationship in very compact terms, e.g. $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$...

Comment: It’s unclear how you are using “perfect” in your question - do you mean is the identities true, or does “perfect” have an artistic meaning?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews nice question:) of course  the first primacy must be its correctness but i meant  an interesting unusual identity by using perfect there

Comment: @gt6989b yes you're right. i see:) thanks for your examples.

Comment: @user1062 See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702396) paper for similar context. Maybe your definition of "perfect" fits somewhere here.

Comment: @soupless it's a very useful paper .thanks:)

Comment: @user1062:  Result not obvious, but correct, a new way of looking at old content in a new bottle, better arranged things that you thought were your territory but indeed differently improved.. makes you tip the hat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though this is a very subjective question, here's one thought on it. Quoting from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*,

> **Theorem (Stokes' Theorem).** If $\omega$ is a ($k-1$)-form on an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c$ is a $k$-chain in $A$, then
> $$ \int_c d \omega = \int_{\partial c} \omega. $$
>
> ...
>
> Stokes' theorem shares three important attributes with many fully evolved major theorems:
>
> 1. It is trivial.
> 2. It is trivial because the terms appearing in it have been properly defined.
> 3. It has significant consequences.
>
> Since this entire chapter was little more than a series of definitions which made the statement and proof of Stokes' theorem possible, the reader should be willing to grant the first two of these attributes to Stokes' theorem. The rest of the book is devoted to justifying the third.

If ever a math textbook had a "thesis statement", that's one there. There's certainly a lot in there: What is a $k$-form, a $k$-chain, an open set? What do $d \omega$ and $\partial c$ and the integral symbols mean? As "nice" as the simple equation looks, it also represents important ideas about how mathematicians can think about real functions in vector spaces.

Or there's the classically "elegant" Euler's Identity,

$$ e^{i \pi}+ 1 = 0 $$

One interesting thing here is that it brings together five of the most important numbers and three of the most important operations (addition, multiplication, exponentiation) in mathematics. We also see $i$, important in the study of basic algebra, $\pi$, important in the study of basic geometry, and $e$, important in the study of basic calculus. And again, it uses and represents the usefulness of certain definitions: what does raising a real number to a complex power even mean? In this case, Euler's Identity isn't itself especially useful - it's just a particularly interesting result of the more general Euler's formula

$$ e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x $$

which does have many useful consequences.

Comment: woow thats great answer.thank you:)